# Vim equivalent of Emacs's C-x C-o (delete-blank-lines)?

Tags: vim, emacs

What's the Vim equivalent of Emacs's <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-o</kbd> (`delete-blank-lines`) function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim does not have a builtin function that does this. Probably the most "vim-like" way to do this is to define a [text-object](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_new_text_objects).

Text objects are an extremely useful vim-feature that allow you to do something like this:

```
dip     "(d)elete (i)nside (p)aragraph
```

or

```
yaW    "(y)ank (a)round this (W)ORD
```

We can define a text object for "empty lines". Let's use 'e' as our mnemonic. That means the features we are looking for are

```
die    "delete inside this empty block (leaving one blank line)
```

and

```
dae    "Delete around this empty block (Leaving no blank lines)
```

The great thing about text-objects, is that adding this will make every other operator work also. So you can do `cie`, or `yie` also. Here's the relevant lines to add to your `.vimrc`

```
vnoremap ie :<C-u>silent! normal! ?^.?+1<C-v><cr>V/^./-1<C-v><cr>k<cr>
onoremap ie :<C-u>silent! normal! ?^.?+1<C-v><cr>V/^./-1<C-v><cr>k<cr>
vnoremap ae :<C-u>silent! normal! ?^.?+1<C-v><cr>V/^./-1<C-v><cr><cr>
onoremap ae :<C-u>silent! normal! ?^.?+1<C-v><cr>V/^./-1<C-v><cr><cr>
```

I won't bother to explain every single one of these (since most of them are very similar) but the basic idea is that we map `ie` to this set of normal mode keystrokes:

```
?^.?+1<C-v><cr>V/^./-1<C-v><cr>k
```

Let's break that down:

```
?               " Search backwards
 ^.             " For a non-blank line
   ?+1          " And offset to one line forward. (So that we find the first blank after a non-blank)
      <C-v><cr> " Enter. (The <C-v> is necessary because we enter it from :normal

"Start a visual selection
V

/                   " Search forwards
 ^.                 " For a non-blank line
   /-1              " And offset to one line backwards. 
      <C-v><cr>     " Enter. (The <C-v> is necessary because we enter it from "normal"
               k    " (optional) if this is an 'i' mapping, not an 'a' mapping, move up one line so that we leave a line
```

This isn't *exactly* the same as emacs does. But then again, you are using vim after all. You shouldn't try to copy the exact same functionality. This will give you a similar functionality while still keeping the same "vim-esque" feel.